# I think I'm adding the path to an image folder incorrectly in the logic of my discord.py bot

Tags: python-3.5, discord.py

I am trying to get the bot to respond with a randomly selected image from a folder on my pc:

```
if message.content == "look at this":

imgList = os.listdir("C:\Users\Alien\Desktop\BOTS\TAL\IMAGES")

imgString = random.choice(imgList)

path = "C:\Users\Alien\Desktop\BOTS\TAL\IMAGES" + imgString

await client.send_file(message.channel, path)
```

This is part of a longer .py file with a lot of different code that all works fine with the necessary intros/outros etc

It ran fine before I added this but now when I try to run it prints:

```
C:\Users\Alien\PycharmProjects\tal-1.0\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Alien/PycharmProjects/tal-1.0/tal-1.0.py
  File "C:/Users/Alien/PycharmProjects/tal-1.0/tal-1.0.py", line 27
    imgList = os.listdir("C:\Users\Alien\Desktop\BOTS\TAL\IMAGES")
                        ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

This is telling you there an escape character error, in position 2-3, which are characters `\U`

`\` is an escape character for strings. It allows you to include things like a single-quote inside a single quote string: `var = 'you\'re'` will keep the single quote without closing the string.

You're using the escape character `\` in your string(, which you're doing because it is part of your filesystem path). So it's trying to decode the next character, `U`, which it doesn't know how to do since it doesn't need to be escaped.

Instead you need to escape the escape character. You'll need to write `\\` in each place that you have `\`.

Your solution needs something like this in all your paths:

```
imgList = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Alien\\Desktop\\BOTS\\TAL\\IMAGES")
```

Comment: You can also tell Python to turn off escaping for that string, which leads to more readable source code (there are some caveats though). `r"C:\Users\Alien\Desktop\BOTS\TAL\IMAGES"`